# R Cannot be resolved to a variable android 4.3

Tags: android, eclipse

[image]I have done almost everything possible. Installed re installed updated to the latest version but nothing seems to work can you please even if i build a new project I get the same error I have installed the latest abt bundle please help me

Comment: Check error in your xml and clean the project

Comment: Did all that still facing errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a local variable JAVA_HOME and problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, these problems are really tricky when they happen. It usually stems from a problem processing your res folder.

Provided that you've already tried cleaning the project & restarting eclipse, here's a few things you should check:

1. Go over all your layouts, string.xmls, dimensions, values, drawable xmls, make sure there's no problems in the xml syntax.
2. Make sure all you xml files or drawable files (pngs, etc) are named correctly: no uppercase values, no special chars... names should only consist of a-z_ characters.

Also, sometimes your console output will provide clues about whats wrong with your res folder.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I have done all that see the point is when I making a new project this problem is coming basically then I just try to run and build the normal hello world program it shows these errors I have not changed anything in the folders still I get this error

Answer (score 0):

This generally occurs when you have got an error in any of your xml file.So please see if there is any.

Comment: This should be comment.

Comment: This happens in a new program also where I have not modified anything and try to run it.

Comment: have you tried cleaning your built??may be it will flash errors in xml if it has.

Comment: Yup I have tried cleaning my file and built it still face errors